# Karma: Running a single test file from command line

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, gulp, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

So, I've been looking all over for this, found "similar" answers here, but not exactly what I want.

Right now if I want to test a single file with karma, I need to do `fit()`, `fdescribe()` on the file in question...

However, what I do want is to be able to just call karma, with the config file, and direct it to a specific file, so I don't need to modify the file at all, ie:

`karma run --conf karma.conf.js --file /path/to/specific/test_file.js`

is it possible to do this? Or with any helper? (using grunt or gulp?)

Comment: Tried `karma run -- --grep=testDescriptionFilter` ? I've seen this suggested before, but I can't verify first hand that it works. (If I were home, I'd try before suggesting. Since I can't try- I'm commenting instead of answering.) :)

Comment: isn't that just for a specific `it` ? No possibility of using it for a file?

Comment: Great question. The place I saw it mentioned was in the context of a single `it` but... seeing as how describes can be nested, maybe it would work for an entire test?

Comment: To be honest, I've always just modified karma.conf if I want to focus on a single test file. It's easy enough to do that I've never spent the effort to find a faster way.

Comment: Well, if you could post this as an answer, I'll accept it, because it seems to work, atm I have 1 describe block per file, so that's alright to use :)

Comment: Hot dog. Glad it helped. Posted. :)

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552729/karma-run-single-test/45350941#45350941

Answer (score 68, accepted):

First you need to start karma server with

```
karma start
```

Then, you can use grep to filter a specific test or describe block:

```
karma run -- --grep=testDescriptionFilter
```

Comment: This answer should say that you should have `karma` running with `karma start` before running `karma run`

Comment: I don't really think that's necessary, given that the question asked about how to filter with `karma run`. Seemed pretty clear that the poster knew how to start Karma and run all tests and was just looking for the syntax regarding filtering.

Comment: What could I do if I want this to happen programmatically? I.e. I wouldn't know the description of the file that changed, but I would know its filename.

Comment: This solution appears not to work at all with Jasmine tests (karma-jasmine).  And the karma run --help does not show --grep as command option at all.  I'm using Karma latest (it says 1.5.0).

Comment: this does not run a single test!

Comment: This answer is 2 years old! ;) Things change.

Comment: This worked for me with `karma-mocha`, but I had to comment out `singleRun: true` in karma.conf.js and run `karma start --no-auto-watch` so that it didn't try running the whole suite from `karma start`...

Answer (score 20):

Even though `--files` is no longer supported, you can use an env variable to provide a list of files:

```
// karma.conf.js
function getSpecs(specList) {
  if (specList) {
    return specList.split(',')
  } else {
    return ['**/*_spec.js'] // whatever your default glob is
  }
}

module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    //...
    files: ['app.js'].concat(getSpecs(process.env.KARMA_SPECS))
  });
});
```

Then in CLI:

```
$ env KARMA_SPECS="spec1.js,spec2.js" karma start karma.conf.js --single-run
```

Comment: This ends up working great!  Just make sure that your default glob has a directory name on the front of it, or else you get a pattern error.  Also, I changed my files: definition like this:
files: [ ].concat(getSpecs(process.env.KARMA_SPECS)),

And that ended up working better, because the function already puts in the glob pattern there if no environment variable is set.  Oh, and I don't think you need the "env " on the front of the command (it works for me without that).  Thanks for this solution @Yuriy Kharchenko !

Answer (score 9):

### This option is no longer supported in recent versions of karma:

see https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1731#issuecomment-174227054

The files array can be redefined using the CLI as such:

```
karma start --files=Array("test/Spec/services/myServiceSpec.js")
```

or escaped:

```
karma start --files=Array\(\"test/Spec/services/myServiceSpec.js\"\)
```

**References**

- [karma-runner source: cli.js](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/lib/cli.js#L24)
- [karma-runner source: config.js](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/blob/master/lib/config.js#L144)

Comment: gives me this error - bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @Lakshay Use the aforementioned escaped syntax for bash `Array\("foo.js"\)`.

Comment: so, when I try this I get the following error: `config.files = config.files.map(createPatternObject).map(createPatternMapper(basePathResolve))`, which might be due to the fact that I'm using requireJS?

Comment: erm, not because of requireJS, for some odd reason karma isn't reading Array("zzz") as being a JS Array? O_o

Comment: nm, it seems that karma no longer supports a --files arg?

Comment: Warning for everyone coming here this option is no longer supported in karma: https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1731#issuecomment-174227054

Answer (score 0):

I tried @Yuriy Kharchenko's solution but ran into a `Expected string or object with "pattern" property` error.

Therefore I made the following modifications to his answer and now I'm able to run single files using Karma:

```
function getSpecs(specList) {
  if (specList) {
    return specList.toString();
  } else {
    return ['**/*_spec.js'] // whatever your default glob is
  }
}


module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    //...
    files: [
        { pattern: getSpecs(process.env.KARMA_SPECS), type: "module"}
    ]
  });
});
```

Note: This solution only works with a single file mentioned in the `KARMA_SPECS` env variable. Ex: `export KARMA_SPECS="src/plugins/muc-views/tests/spec1.js"`