# How do you test one file (from the command line) with a Vue webpack project?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, karma-webpack

I [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150998/karma-running-a-single-test-file-from-command-line) that you could run `karma start` and then `karma run -- --grep=testDescriptionFilter` to run a test for just one file. However, when I try to do that in a project where I am using Vue and got started with the [webpack template](http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/), it doesn't work.

I've tried editing the `files` array in `karma.conf.js`, in hopes of being able to test one file this way. Normally the array looks like this:

```
files: [
  '../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  '../../node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
  './index.js'
],
```

And `index.js` looks like this:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

// require all test files (files that ends with .spec.js)
const testsContext = require.context('./specs', true, /\.spec$/)
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext)

// require all src files except main.js for coverage.
// you can also change this to match only the subset of files that
// you want coverage for.
const srcContext = require.context('../../src', true, /^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$)/)
srcContext.keys().forEach(srcContext)
```

First I tried to include the file I want to test instead of `./index.js` like so:

```
files: [
  '../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  '../../node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
  './specs/players/OutcomeAnalyzerPlayer/setRangesAccordingToFilters/afterPreflop1/afterFlop1.spec.js'
],
```

When I do that, I get a `SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'import'` error:

```
code/premium-poker-tools [master●] » npm run unit

> premium-poker-tools@1.0.0 unit /Users/adamzerner/code/premium-poker-tools
> BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js

18 10 2018 12:25:49.014:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
18 10 2018 12:25:49.021:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
18 10 2018 12:25:49.022:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
18 10 2018 12:25:49.026:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
18 10 2018 12:25:49.801:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 1jJ_7wJ0bOiMO299AAAA with id 58854798
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'import'
  at specs/players/OutcomeAnalyzerPlayer/setRangesAccordingToFilters/afterPreflop1/afterFlop1.spec.js:1

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
```

I'm not sure why I'm getting that error, but after looking through that `./index.js` file, it looks like it is necessary, and that if I want to specify that I want to only run the specs for a certain file, I'll have to do it there. So I tried creating a `set-ranges-according-to-filters.js` file that only includes the file i want to test, and is otherwise the same as `index.js`:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

// require all test files (files that ends with .spec.js)
const testsContext = require.context('./specs/players/OutcomeAnalyzerPlayer/setRangesAccordingToFilters/afterPreflop1/afterFlop1.spec.js', true, /\.spec$/)
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext)

// require all src files except main.js for coverage.
// you can also change this to match only the subset of files that
// you want coverage for.
const srcContext = require.context('../../src', true, /^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$)/)
srcContext.keys().forEach(srcContext)
```

Then I updated the `files` array in `karma.conf.js`:

```
files: [
  '../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  '../../node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
  './set-ranges-according-to-filters.js'
],
```

and ran karma. I again get the same error:

```
code/premium-poker-tools [master●] » npm run unit

> premium-poker-tools@1.0.0 unit /Users/adamzerner/code/premium-poker-tools
> BABEL_ENV=test karma start test/unit/karma.conf.js

18 10 2018 12:30:35.072:WARN [karma]: No captured browser, open http://localhost:9876/
18 10 2018 12:30:35.087:INFO [karma]: Karma v1.7.1 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
18 10 2018 12:30:35.087:INFO [launcher]: Launching browser PhantomJS with unlimited concurrency
18 10 2018 12:30:35.119:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
18 10 2018 12:30:35.937:INFO [PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket 5-U0Mca0_Vgr07-rAAAA with id 87593561
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0) ERROR
  SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'import'
  at set-ranges-according-to-filters.js:1

PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Mac OS X 0.0.0): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
TOTAL: 0 SUCCESS
```

Preferably, I'd like to be able to test one file from the command line, something like `karma start --file-path-to-my-file`. But if that isn't possible, being able to edit `karma.conf.js` so that it only runs the tests for my file would be an ok consolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## By editing `test/unit/index.js`

One way is by editing `test/unit/index.js`. The following code for `test/unit/index.js` tests the file I wanted to test:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

// require all test files (files that ends with .spec.js)
const testsContext = require.context('./specs/players/OutcomeAnalyzerPlayer/setRangesAccordingToFilters/afterPreflop1', true, /afterFlop1\.spec\.js/)
testsContext.keys().forEach(testsContext)

// require all src files except main.js for coverage.
// you can also change this to match only the subset of files that
// you want coverage for.
const srcContext = require.context('../../src', true, /^\.\/(?!main(\.js)?$)/)
srcContext.keys().forEach(srcContext)
```

Note that my initial attempt at using [`require.context`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/dependency-management/) - `require.context('./specs/players/OutcomeAnalyzerPlayer/setRangesAccordingToFilters/afterPreflop1/afterFlop1.spec.js', true, /\.spec$/)` - wouldn't have worked. The first argument is a *folder*, not a file. The second argument is a flag indicating whether subdirectories should be searched too, and the third is a regex to match files against.

---

I initially tried to create a different file in place of `test/unit/index.js` and include it in `files` instead of `./index.js`. The reason why I was getting the `SyntaxError: Use of reserved word 'import'` error is because `import` is an ES6 feature that isn't part of Node. It needs webpack to make it available. To get it working, I had to add it to the `preprocessors` array in `karma.conf.js` like so:

```
files: [
  '../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  '../../node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
  // './index.js'
  './set-ranges-according-to-filters.js'
],
preprocessors: {
  './index.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
  './set-ranges-according-to-filters.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
},
```

## By directly including the file in the `files` array

Directly including the file in the `files` array instead of `./index.js` works too:

```
files: [
  '../../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  '../../node_modules/babel-polyfill/dist/polyfill.js',
  // './index.js'
  '../../src/services/monkey-patches.js',
  './specs/players/OutcomeAnalyzerPlayer/setRangesAccordingToFilters/afterPreflop1/afterFlop1.spec.js'
],
```

There are two caveats (that I could think of) though:

1) Using `./index.js` includes other specs and src files. When you just add your file directly instead of using `./index.js`, those other files don't get loaded, and that could cause stuff to break. It did for me, and I had to add something to the `files` array in front of my spec to get it to work.

2) I needed to add the following to the `preprocessors` array:

```
preprocessors: {
  // './index.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
  '../../src/services/monkey-patches.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap'],
  './specs/players/OutcomeAnalyzerPlayer/setRangesAccordingToFilters/afterPreflop1/afterFlop1.spec.js': ['webpack', 'sourcemap']
},
```

## Using the command line

I wasn't able to get the `karma run -- --grep=testDescriptionFilter` [approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150998/karma-running-a-single-test-file-from-command-line) working. And when I run `karma run --help` and `karma start --help`, I don't see any options for running the tests of a specific file.

If you really want to, you could create different karma configuration files that run tests for different files, and then create scripts in `package.json` to run your tests with different configuration files. Eg. `karma-1.conf.js` would run the tests for `file-1.spec.js`, and then you could have a `npm run unit-1` command that runs `karma start test/unit/karma-1.conf.js`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "unit-1": "karma start test/unit/karma-1.conf.js"
  }
}
```