# How to run single .spec file in angular5

Tags: node.js, jasmine, angular5, karma-jasmine

Hi i am writing unit test for my application using jasmine and karma.
I want to run individual test file for testing not as a whole project using npm test.
I don't want to us `fdescribe()`and  `fit()`.
Is there any way i can run my test file by providing filename while running test for the same.

Comment: Did you have a look into [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29150998/karma-running-a-single-test-file-from-command-line) ?

Comment: posible dupplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552729/karma-run-single-test/55525936#55525936