# Karma not running a specific test file. Instead, it run all test files

Tags: karma-jasmine, karma-runner

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45350941/4148175 part A I should be able to run a specific test file by "karma start --grep my-test-file.js". I tried but it run two test files I have.

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/29151264/4148175 I should firstly start karma and then run the specific file but after I started karma I also have my two files triggered and when I try run the spesific file I get that the port isn't answering.

As far as I understood, I must setup autoWatch: true and singleRun: true and it is that way in my karma.conf.js

Console:

```
# karma start
03 07 2019 14:02:29.713:WARN [filelist]: Pattern "C:/_d/samples/../node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js" does not match any file.
03 07 2019 14:02:29.730:INFO [karma-server]: Karma v4.1.0 server started at http://0.0.0.0:9876/
03 07 2019 14:02:29.731:INFO [launcher]: Launching browsers Chrome, Firefox with concurrency unlimited
03 07 2019 14:02:29.739:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
03 07 2019 14:02:29.754:INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
03 07 2019 14:02:35.891:INFO [Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0)]: Connected on socket R657DrSW7GAKGkPxAAAA with id 98561767

**** certain test from a file

**** another test from other file

Chrome 75.0.3770 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 6 of 6 SUCCESS (0.096 secs / 0.01 secs)
Firefox 67.0.0 (Windows 10.0.0): Executed 6 of 6 SUCCESS (0.073 secs / 0.017 secs)
TOTAL: 12 SUCCESS


mycompany@DESKTOPF C:\_d\samples\how-to-test-web-component
# karma run -- --grep=text.component.test.js
03 07 2019 14:03:02.469:ERROR [runner]: There is no server listening on port 9876
```

Karma.conf.js

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: "",
    frameworks: ["jasmine"],
    files: [
      "node_modules/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-bundle.js",
      { pattern: "**/*.test.js", type: "module", included: true },
      { pattern: "**/*.js", type: "module", included: false }
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ["spec"],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ["Chrome", "Firefox"],
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
  });
};
```

To summarize: what I am doing wrong or missing in order to test via karma just the tests found in a specific file?

Comment: did you try `fdescribe` or `fit` instead of `describe` and `it` blocks ?

Comment: I am currently fighting with similar symptoms. Maybe the origin is different, but for sure debugging is not easy. logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG, gives a lot of informations.