# have Karma keep browser and test results open longer

Tags: karma-runner, webpack

[This project](https://github.com/justinwoo/react-karma-webpack-testing/) with an accompanying[blog post](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/test-reactjs-components-karma-webpack#/) demonstrates how to use Karma with React.js but when you run `npm run test` Karma opens the browser very quickly and shuts it down almost as quickly, not allowing you to debug the application (which its supposed to do). I changed the config to `singleRun: false`, thinking it might be `singleRun` that's shutting the application down.

I also added `autoWatch: true` hoping it would keep the test results visible but that didn't work either.

Question: how to get karma to keep the browser open long enough to view the test results and debug the application?

This is the karma.config.js file

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({

    // browsers: [ process.env.CONTINUOUS_INTEGRATION ? 'Firefox' : 'Chrome' ],
    browsers: [ 'Chrome' ],

    singleRun: true,

    // autoWatch: true,

    frameworks: [ 'mocha' ],

    files: [
      'tests.webpack.js'
    ],

    preprocessors: {
      'tests.webpack.js': [ 'webpack', 'sourcemap' ]
    },

    reporters: [ 'dots' ],

    webpack: {
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      module: {
        loaders: [
          { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader' }
        ]
      }
    },

    webpackServer: {
      noInfo: true
    }

  });
};
```

Comment: The `singleRun: true` option kills your browser after running the tests.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Referencing to the [official docs](http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html) the default name of the Karma configuration file is `karma.conf.js`, make sure that yours is named correctly.

Regarding to the leaving the browser window opened, I've encountered with a similar issue and my solution was running the Karma directly with `--auto-watch` flag. Try `$ karma start --auto-watch` instead of `$ npm run test` *(make sure that you've installed `karma-cli` globally via `$ npm install -g karma-cli`)*.

You also should checkout the `scripts:` configuration section in your `package.json` file. Some forcing options might be specified there.

Comment: i'm here looking for which flags and options control the length of karma's timeout and restart, but this answer is pretty vague: "reference the docs"? "try some flags"? "check your package.json"?

Answer (score 4):

The `singleRun:false` option auto-recovers closed browser windows. You will need to execute `karma stop` or kill the process. That was very annoying for me.

The watch mode of Karma was also annoying for me since I have > 2500 tests that take a long time to execute. I don't want to trigger that on every file change.

Using Gulp in combination with the Karma API provides more flexibility.

Following example can be used for testing a single file and keeping the browser open until it is manually closed. It applies the **browsers_change** event of Karma to stop the server.

Related infos:

- https://karma-runner.github.io/0.13/dev/public-api.html
- [Karma run single test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26552729/karma-run-single-test/45350941#45350941)

---

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var karma = require('karma');
var KarmaServerConstructor = karma.Server;
var karmaStopper = karma.stopper;   
var commandLineArguments = require('yargs').argv;

    //Executes only one test which has to be passed as command line argument --filePath
    //The option --browser also has to be passed as command line argument.
    //Example usage:  gulp single --browser="Chrome_With_Saved_DevTools_Settings" --filePath="C:\myTest.spec.js"
    gulp.task('single', function (done) {     

        var filePath = commandLineArguments.filePath.replace(/\\/g, "/");

        var karmaOptions = {
            configFile: __dirname + '/karma.conf.js',
            action: 'start',        
            browsers: [commandLineArguments.browser],       
            files: [
                './Leen.Managementsystem/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
                './Leen.Managementsystem/bower_components/globalize/lib/globalize.js',
                { pattern: './Leen.Managementsystem/bower_components/**/*.js', included: false },
                { pattern: './Leen.Managementsystem.Tests/App/test/mockFactory.js', included: false },
                { pattern: './Leen.Managementsystem/App/**/*.js', included: false },
                { pattern: './Leen.Managementsystem.Tests/App/test/*.js', included: false },
                { pattern: filePath, included: false },
                './Leen.Managementsystem.Tests/App/test-main.js',
                './switchKarmaToDebugTab.js' //also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33023535/open-karma-debug-html-page-on-startup
            ]
        };

        var karmaServer = new KarmaServerConstructor(karmaOptions, done);   
        karmaServer.on('browsers_change', stopServerIfAllBrowsersAreClosed);
        karmaServer.start();     
    });

   function stopServerIfAllBrowsersAreClosed(browsers) {
  if (browsers.length === 0) {

//double check since browser might only be closed temporarily due to connection issues
setTimeout(function () {
  if (browsers.length === 0) {
    karmaStopper.stop();
  }
}, 2000);   
  }
}
```