# Run angular Karma tests in visual studio code

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I installed `vscode-test-explorer` extension along with its child `angular-karma-test-explorer` and `jasmine-test-adapter` to vscode as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55525936/1657465).

However, no tests are loaded to the Test Explorer, it shows these projects to choose from but nothing loads:
[image]

angular-cli.json:

```js
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "project": {
        "name": "frontend-cli"
    },
    "apps": [
        {
            "name": "debug",
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist",
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "scripts": [
                "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            ],
            "environmentSource": "app/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "release",
            "root": "src",
            "outDir": "dist",
            "index": "index.html",
            "main": "main.ts",
            "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
            "test": "test.ts",
            "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "prefix": "app",
            "scripts": [
                "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
            ],
            "environmentSource": "app/environment.ts",
            "environments": {
                "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
                "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
            }
        }
    ],
    "e2e": {
        "protractor": {
            "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "test": {
        "karma": {
            "config": "./karma.conf.js"
        }
    },
    "defaults": {
        "styleExt": "scss",
        "component": {}
    }
}
```

my karma.conf.js

```js
// Karma configuration file, see link for more information
// https://karma-runner.github.io/1.0/config/configuration-file.html

module.exports = function (config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        files: [],
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular/cli'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-spec-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular/cli/plugins/karma')
        ],
        specReporter: {
            maxLogLines: -1, // Limit number of lines logged per test
            suppressErrorSummary: false, // Do not print error summary
            suppressFailed: false, // Do not print information about failed tests
            suppressPassed: true, // Do not print information about passed tests
            suppressSkipped: true, // Do not print information about skipped tests
            showSpecTiming: false, // Print the time elapsed for each spec
            failFast: false // Test would finish with error when a first fail occurs.
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: ['text-summary', 'html', 'lcovonly'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
            thresholds: {
                emitWarning: true, // Remove once the hard-working frontend developers finished their tests
                global: {
                    statements: 100,
                    lines: 100,
                    branches: 100,
                    functions: 100
                }
            }
        },
        angularCli: {
            environment: 'dev'
        },
        reporters: [
            'spec',
            'kjhtml' // Seems to stop working when kjhtml is removed
        ],
        port: 9876,
        colors: false,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: true,
        singleRun: false,
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadlessCI'],
        browserDisconnectTimeout: 10000,
        browserDisconnectTolerance: 2,
        browserNoActivityTimeout: 60000,
        browserConsoleLogOptions: {
            level: 'debug',
            format: "%b %T: %m",
            terminal: true
        },
        client: {
            clearContext: false, // Leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
            captureConsole: true
        },
        customLaunchers: {
            ChromeHeadlessCI: {
                base: 'ChromeHeadless',
                flags: [
                    '--no-sandbox',
                    '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
                    '--disable-gpu',
                    '--disable-web-security',
                    '--disable-software-rasterizer',
                    '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
                    '--disable-translate',
                    '--disable-extensions'
                ]
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Shouldn't it show `src` as the project to test?
In the documentation (https://github.com/Raagh/angular-karma_test-explorer/blob/master/DOCUMENTATION.md) I see you can define the project, but I'm not sure where to put the setting?

package.json:

```js
{
    "name": "frontend2",
    "version": "0.0.0",
    "license": "MIT",
    "scripts": {
        "ng": "ng",
        "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json",
        "build": "ng build",
        "build-prod": "node --max-old-space-size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --app=release --sourcemaps -prod",
        "test": "ng test --watch=false --single-run=true",
        "test-coverage": "ng test --watch=false --single-run=true --code-coverage",
        "test-watch": "ng test",
        "test-watch-coverage": "ng test --code-coverage",
    },
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "5.1.1",
        "@angular/common": "5.1.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "5.1.1",
        "@angular/core": "5.1.1",
        "@angular/forms": "5.1.1",
        "@angular/http": "5.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "5.1.1",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.1.1",
        "@angular/router": "5.1.1",
        "@sentry/browser": "^5.6.2",
        "ag-grid": "^16.0.0",
        "ag-grid-angular": "^16.0.0",
        "angular2-notifications": "^1.0.0",
        "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
        "color-parse": "^1.3.8",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "signalr": "^2.2.2",
        "ua-parser-js": "^0.7.20",
        "web-animations-js": "^2.3.1",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "^1.7.4",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.11",
        "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/highcharts": "^5.0.22",
        "@types/jasmine": "^3.3.12",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.6",
        "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
        "@types/signalr": "^2.2.35",
        "@types/ua-parser-js": "^0.7.33",
        "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
        "gulp": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-cheerio": "^0.6.3",
        "gulp-clean": "^0.4.0",
        "gulp-cli": "^2.2.0",
        "gulp-download": "0.0.1",
        "gulp-rename": "^1.4.0",
        "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2",
        "gulp-svgmin": "^2.2.0",
        "gulp-svgstore": "^7.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "^3.4.0",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
        "karma": "^4.3.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
        "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.0.5",
        "karma-failed-reporter": "0.0.3",
        "karma-jasmine": "^2.0.1",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
        "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.5",
        "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.32",
        "ng2-completer": "^2.0.8",
        "protractor": "^5.4.2",
        "protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
        "sass-variable-parser": "^1.2.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "tslint-eslint-rules": "^5.4.0",
        "typescript": "^2.6.2"
    }
}
```

```js
   
angular-cli.json
package.json
karma.conf.json
-src
--app
---services
----data.service.spec.ts
---components
----data.component.spec.ts
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior. I ran into this a few months back when I first tried to get this working. Gave up. Trying again now hoping that some update has fixed this. Still no luck :(

Comment: Extension `angular-karma-text-explorer` has been [deprecated in DEC/2021](https://github.com/Raagh/angular-karma_test-explorer/commit/3748499fb078161f69829b1b66aff751d14cea8c), try [karma-test-explorer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lucono.karma-test-explorer) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your `package.json`, it seems that you are using an older version of `Angular CLI (^1.7.4)` and not the newer `Angular CLI` version that uses `angular.json` for configuration.

Try this:

- Uninstall test explorer.
- Update Angular CLI.
- Reinstall test explorer.